# How to use sscanf to extract float numbers?

Tags: c++

I have one string like: 
`string line="Name &0.11/-0.11 &0.11/0.11 &0.03/0.03 \\";`

And I want to extract name and all float numbers, I tried:

`sscanf(line,"%s %*[&]%f%*[/]%f %*[&]%f%*[/]%f %*[&]%f%*[/]%f %*[\\]",systname,&sig_up,&sig_down,&prompt_up,&prompt_down,&Vgam_up,&Vgam_down);`

But it didn't work, and got error:`Error: sscanf parameter mismatch param[0] C u`
Could someone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sweet lord. Sure you're not better off splitting the string first, and then parsing the elements individually?

Comment: The code you posted works https://ideone.com/90jxiV Please review your question and provide an example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Isn't `%*[&]` equivalent to just `&`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It should be `line.c_str()`..Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

%f matches a double in printf() and its family, a float in scanf() and its family. Usually you want to work in double precision, so you need %lf for scanf().

However strtod() is more stable and error-resistant.